# How to align icon to center inside div element?

Tags: html, css, css-position, center

I would like to center icon to the div element "rectangle". Any other alternative solution is also welcomed.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.rectangle {
  width: 125px;
 height: 125px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #fff;
}

h3 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="rectangle">
  <span><i class="fa fa-quora" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 75px;" align="center"></i></span>
</div>
<h3>Quora</h3>
```

Comment: looking for responsive solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19461521/483779

Comment: @putvande: His attempt is already in his question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey not really. There is nothing in there about positioning so therefore there is no effort in my mind.

Comment: @putvande: "Prior effort" is not a requirement for asking questions here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to `.rectangle` and the following CSS for the icon:

```
.fa-quora {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.rectangle {
    width: 125px;
 height: 125px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
.fa-quora {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
h3 {
   color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="rectangle">
  <span><i class="fa fa-quora" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 75px;"></i></span>
</div>
<h3>Quora</h3>
```

Answer (score 8):

By adding this to your `.rectangle` class

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

Sample snippet

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.rectangle {
  width: 125px;
 height: 125px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h3 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="rectangle">
  <span><i class="fa fa-quora" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 75px;" align="center"></i></span>
</div>
<h3>Quora</h3>
```

---

If you want to support older browsers, add this to your `.rectangle` class

```
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Sample snippet

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.rectangle {
  width: 125px;
 height: 125px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #fff;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

h3 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="rectangle">
  <span><i class="fa fa-quora" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 75px;" align="center"></i></span>
</div>
<h3>Quora</h3>
```

Comment: +1 because I believe more people should start using flexbox. It's amazing how many lines of JavaScript it can save you.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.rectangle {
  width: 125px;
 height: 125px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
}

h3 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="rectangle">
  <span><i class="fa fa-quora" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 75px; position: absolute; left: 50%;"></i></span>
</div>
<h3>Quora</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your asking...

You can add some pixels in `padding-left` and `padding-top` on `rectangle` class. After that your reduce the width and the height with the same number of pixels. But other characters than Q can have a different rendering.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.rectangle {
    width: 98px;
    height: 98px;
    padding-top: 22px;
    padding-left: 22px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

h3 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="rectangle">
        <span><i class="fa fa-quora" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 75px;" align="center"></i></span>
    </div>
<h3>Quora</h3>
```

Here is another example without fixing height. It's using flex.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.rectangle {
    width:125px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

h3 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="rectangle">
  <span><i class="fa fa-quora" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 75px;" align="center"></i></span>
</span>
<h3>Quora</h3>
```